# Перенаправление лога slf4j

Tags: java, slf4j

Использую библиотеку [Parallec](https://github.com/eBay/parallec), которая в свою очередь ведет логи в slf4j. Скажите можно ли перенаправить сообщения заданного уровня (WARN и страшнее) в файл?

Находил описание конфигурационного файла, но он на нее не реагирует. log4j не подключен.

Comment: вы говорите об этой библиотеке [https://github.com/eBay/parallec](https://github.com/eBay/parallec)?

Comment: Да, сейчас ссылку в вопрос добавлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЕМНИП, slf4j - это универсальный фасад логгирования, т.е. для его корректной работы нужна конкретная библиотека логгирования, log4j например.
Чтоб заработало Вам нужен конкретный биндинг на конкретную бибилиотеку логгирования. Более подробно можно ознакомиться в [официальном руководстве пользователя slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html).

Comment: Добавил, также подцепил конфиг для log4j. Ну да, Hibernate среагировал, а parallec нет.

Comment: @RiĥardBrugekĥaim а своих логов библиотека не ведет? В отдельном файле я имею ввиду. Судя по исходникам, там есть настройка для logback.

Comment: А вот его наличие я не заметил. Спасибо, настроил.